# Why does DateOffset.rollback() not work the way I expect it to with days / hours?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, offset, datetimeoffset

I'm trying to move an arbitrary input `pd.Timestamp` back to the correct start offset unless it is already on offset.

The following code works with `BusinessMonthEnd`, `MonthEnd`, `MonthStart`, and so on:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import *


def to_start(t: pd.Timestamp, freq: pd.DateOffset) -> pd.Timestamp:
    return freq.rollback(t)


assert to_start(pd.to_datetime("2021-09-27"), MonthEnd()) == pd.to_datetime("2021-08-31")
assert to_start(pd.to_datetime("2021-09-27"), MonthBegin()) == pd.to_datetime("2021-08-31")
assert to_start(pd.to_datetime("2021-08-27"), BMonthEnd()) == pd.to_datetime("2021-07-30")
assert to_start(pd.to_datetime("2021-08-27"), YearBegin()) == pd.to_datetime("2021-01-01")
assert to_start(pd.to_datetime("2021-08-27"), BYearBegin()) == pd.to_datetime("2021-01-01")

# also it works nicely with holiday calendars
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar

us_fed_biz_days = CustomBusinessDay(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())
memorial_day = pd.to_datetime("2021-05-31")
the_friday_before_memorial_day = pd.to_datetime("2021-05-28")
assert to_start(memorial_day, us_fed_biz_days) == the_friday_before_memorial_day
```

However (and this is driving me crazy) it doesn't seem to work for `Day`, `BusinessDay`, `Week`, `Hour` etc:

```py
assert to_start(pd.to_datetime("2021-08-27 05:00"), Day()) == pd.to_datetime("2021-08-27")
assert to_start(pd.to_datetime("2021-08-27 05:00"), BDay()) == pd.to_datetime("2021-08-27")
assert to_start(pd.to_datetime("2021-08-27 05:15"), Hour()) == pd.to_datetime("2021-08-27 05:00")
assert to_start(pd.to_datetime("2021-08-26"), pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset("W-MON")) == pd.to_datetime("2021-08-24")
```

I have also tried this:

```py
def to_start(t: pd.Timestamp, freq: pd.DateOffset) -> pd.Timestamp:
        return pd.Period(t, freq=freq).start_time
```

which ironically works with the second set of assertions but not the first?

Is my expectation of the above assertions not failing unreasonable, and if so what am I missing, please?

Comment: if you have a look that the function in the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/5d21d1350aacfa44d83969395d1bc6feb1fccbd4/pandas/_libs/tslibs/offsets.pyx#L625) you'll find that it makes a difference which kind of offset you're using in the comparison - in the upper part of your example, you have variable offsets (in comparison to given date/time), in the lower part, the offsets are fixed (BDay kind of in-between).

Comment: I edited the question to remove the `is_on_offset()` call that was not needed. I also added another use case with holidays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your examples, I take it that you want to use fixed frequencies (e.g. an hour) to floor the given date/time while variable frequencies (e.g. business month end) should call `.rollback` if the check given in `.is_on_offset` returns True (see source code linked in the questions' comment section).

Ex:

```
def to_start(t: pd.Timestamp, freq: pd.DateOffset) -> pd.Timestamp:
    try:
        return t.floor(freq) # fixed frequencies should just floor the date/time
    except ValueError: # if freq is variable, we fall into here...
        return freq.rollback(t.floor("D"))
```

Tests:

```
# variable offsets that depend on the date
assert to_start(pd.to_datetime("2021-09-27"), pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd()) == pd.to_datetime("2021-08-31")
assert to_start(pd.to_datetime("2021-09-27"), pd.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin()) == pd.to_datetime("2021-09-01")
assert to_start(pd.to_datetime("2021-08-27"), pd.tseries.offsets.BMonthEnd()) == pd.to_datetime("2021-07-30")
assert to_start(pd.to_datetime("2021-08-27"), pd.tseries.offsets.YearBegin()) == pd.to_datetime("2021-01-01")
assert to_start(pd.to_datetime("2021-08-27"), pd.tseries.offsets.BYearBegin()) == pd.to_datetime("2021-01-01")
assert to_start(pd.to_datetime("2021-08-26"), pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset("W-MON")) == pd.to_datetime("2021-08-23")
assert to_start(pd.to_datetime("2021-08-28 05:00"), pd.tseries.offsets.BDay()) == pd.to_datetime("2021-08-27")
# fixed offsets (e.g. an hour is always an hour)
assert to_start(pd.to_datetime("2021-08-27 05:00"), pd.tseries.offsets.Day()) == pd.to_datetime("2021-08-27")
assert to_start(pd.to_datetime("2021-08-27 05:15"), pd.tseries.offsets.Hour()) == pd.to_datetime("2021-08-27 05:00")
```

Comment: I'm taking a look at the source code and your code but in the meantime would like to point out that this doesn't work:
```assert to_start(pd.to_datetime("2021-08-26"), pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset("W-MON")) == pd.to_datetime("2021-08-24")```
as it incorrectly returns `2021-08-23` which is a Sunday.

Comment: @ilCatania are you sure? according to my calendar, it's a Monday. In general, you're right, I didn't write a comprehensive test for this, so make sure to do so.

Comment: @ilCatania addendum - I think you can always floor to the day if you have a variable offset (freq) input, see my edit.

Comment: you're right, I was looking at the wrong month. Ok so this is great news!

Comment: I've ran several additional tests and this works. Thank you for your help!